# Durandal dialog Call back Function

Tags: durandal-2.0

In my view model I have a grid, if user click on Edit button on the row it will popup a dialog with row values, if user click on Edit button will close the dialog then I need to reload the grid. My model look like below, I my case 
I am not able to **call load function** after dialog call back (** getting Error - self is undefined**). it is possible to pass **this** to dialog?

```
var ctor = function () {
         var self = this;
         self.load = function () {
             Load grid Functions
         }
         self.editRow = function (row) {
             dialog.show(new editWindow(), row).then(function (response) {
                 if (response == null) {
                     return;
                 }
                 self.load();
             });
         }

         Return ctor;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got answer  by adding **self** with call back

```
var ctor = function () {
         var self = this;
         self.load = function () {
             Load grid Functions
         }
         self.editRow = function (row) {
             dialog.show(new editWindow(), row).then(function (response) {
                 if (response == null) {
                     return;
                 }
                 self.load();
             },self);
         }

         Return ctor;
```